# Everyone recommended lightbox... it still doesn't do what it apparently should

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I'm trying to make an image gallery on my site so that I can put screenshots onto blog articles where they will be relevant. After spending several hours working on a custom jquery solution using my own code and getting no help whatsoever from anywhere on the net, I caved and decided to use lightbox.

I followed the instructions to set it up [on this page](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) however, it still does nothing. Essentially all I've done is put a link to the image on my page...

Here's my code as rendered on the page (url below):

```
<head>
    <link href="/js/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--[if lte IE9]>
        <link href="/css/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="/js/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/lightbox/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- skipping irrelevant content -->

    <h3 id="screenshots">Screenshots</h3>
    <div class="screenshots">
        <a href="http://loganyoung.za.net/images/articles/logan-mvc-error-big.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
        <a href="http://loganyoung.za.net/images/articles/logan-mvc-error-big.png" data-lightbox="MVCError"><img src="http://www.loganyoung.za.net/images/articles/logan-mvc-error-big.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" class="alignleft" /></a>
        <a href="http://loganyoung.za.net/images/articles/logan-mvc-error-small.png" data-lightbox="MVCError"><img src="http://www.loganyoung.za.net/images/articles/logan-mvc-error-small.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" class="alignleft" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- skipping more irrelevant content -->
</body>
</html>
```

**URL** http://loganyoung.za.net/error-reporting-in-mvc/

If anyone can tell me what I did wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Include jQuery before the lightbox.

Comment: see, now if the conceded wastes of human life that I had been talking to had just taken a second to help me, I wouldn't have got so frustrated as to miss something that simple... thanks a lot!

Comment: Firebug: `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` Chrome developer tools: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `, so I guess your first error is not to use the proper tools...

Comment: No they were used, I just had them in the wrong place as per j08691

Comment: @Ortund `conceded wastes of human life` ???  seriously??? the error was mentioned on line 1 by the most basic tools any webdev should master, so tone down a bit.

Comment: @fvu you're right... something I'd have noticed and acted upon had people who are too good to help a guy out just helped me instead of giving me half or non answers thereby causing me to become incredibly frustrated (I've been working on this for hours before looking at lightbox - hence the frustration)

Comment: @Ortund You didn't even ***look*** at the debugger console, get over it, don't blame others and their perceived attitude problem for something so basic that ***you*** missed.  Coming to terms with ones own limitations and occasional phases of blindness is a key ingredient to survive in programming :)

Comment: How is "Include jQuery before the lightbox." a half answer? It's like saying put your key in the ignition before starting your car!

Comment: @Macsupport you're basing assumptions on half the information. Half answers came before the jquery reference faux pas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made sure jQuery was referenced in the right place (above all the lightbox crap) woopdeedoo